# If $(AA^\dagger+A^\dagger A)\vec v\propto \vec v$ is $A A^\dagger \vec v\propto \vec v$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let us say we have a matrix $A$, such that the vector $\vec v$ is an eigenvector of:
$$A A^\dagger +A^\dagger A$$
i.e.:
$$(A A^\dagger +A^\dagger A)\vec v=\lambda \vec v$$
Is it possible to say that:
$$A A^\dagger \vec v=\mu \vec v$$
i.e. that $\vec v$ is also an eigenvector of $A A^\dagger$ and can this be proved either way?

Comment: The daggers are meant to denote matrix transposes correct? or conjugate transposes?

Comment: Can we say anything about eigenvalues of $A^*$ from eigenvalues of $A$? What do eigenvalues of self-adjoint operators look like? Are any of your operators self-adjoint?

Comment: @William they are meant to denote conjugate transposes.